# Dataprep sort in reverse order does not work, any solutions?

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I've come across a very annoying bug in Google Dataprep.

According to this page: https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Window-Transform_57344658, it should be possible to reverse the order of sorting by adding a dash in front of the column name.

However, although the preview shows that the data is correctly sorted, the output will always be sorted in ascending order.

I have tested it in various ways and I'm sure it is a bug in the system.

The formula I'm trying to use is a `PREV(column_name, 1)` function which is not grouped, but is ordered by `column_name` and `-date`.

To subsequently deduplicate the dataset based on this column: `If(window==column_name)`

Hopefully it will be solved as soon as possible. The current situation asks for a workaround. Does anyone know an elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to reproduce the issue you reported when using a Window function ordered in reverse order using a dash `-OrderColumn`.

I see that you have already created a [Dataprep issue in Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/77939635) and another member of the GCP Support team was also able to reproduce this behavior and reported it to the Dataprep team. Cloud Dataprep is a third party product developed and managed by a company called Trifacta, and this issue requires support from their product team. I see that the Trifacta Dataprep team is working on the issue reported, and their first response is that, while they work on this, a quick workaround is to use sort in a separate step.

As a final note, maybe next time you can share screenshots in your question in order to provide an easier understanding of your issue.